# Media query in HTML link is not linking to separate CSS file

Tags: html, css

When I use media query to link to multiple CSS files from an HTML link, only the full-size css file applies.

I am able to get the media queries to work successfully within one single CSS file using:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
body {
    /* style changes */
}
```

However, I want separate files for each media query.  Here is my test code which does not work for me:

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='mobile.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet'  href='stylesheet.css' />   
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

mobile.css

```
body {
    background-color:red;
}
```

stylesheet.css

```
body {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

All the files are correctly named and saved within the same folder.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the order in which you are linking the CSS files.

You need the mobile.css classes to override the ones specified in stylesheet.css, so include it second.

```
<link rel='stylesheet'  href='stylesheet.css' />  
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='mobile.css' />
```